# ORMLite does not support GregorianCalendar to be mapped

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm going to use ORMLite as I have found it very useful... However, I have found a disadvantage.

I have a class which has a GregorianCalendar type attribute, which is mapped as follows:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING)
private GregorianCalendar fechaNacimiento;
```

When I run my app, it gets crashed with that message in logcat:

> 07-31 20:52:47.629: E/AndroidRuntime(11808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-31 20:52:47.629: E/AndroidRuntime(11808): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joninazio.euskofest/com.joninazio.euskofest.ui.MenuPrincipalActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class java.util.GregorianCalendar for field FieldType:name=fechaCreacion,class=Usuario is not valid for type com.j256.ormlite.field.types.DateStringType@40dca268, maybe should be class [B
>   07-31 20:52:47.629: E/AndroidRuntime(11808):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)

It seems that GregorianCalendar is not supported by OrmLite as it can be seen here: http://ormlite.com/data_types.shtml, which states that OrmLite's DATE corresponds to Java's java.util.Date...

And my question is why supporting a deprecated class?

Do you have any solution not to change GregorianCalendar? Perhaps changing the annotation to

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
```

?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with a trick:

- The data to be persisted change to Date class. Change or create new setters and getters.
- Create the GregorianCalendar attribute, but that one not persisted (without annotations).
- Modify the setter of the Date attribute, assign the GregorianCalendar Date's value converted.

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar class implements the Serializable interface. GregorianCalendar extends Calendar.

You can declare your field with the following:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
private GregorianCalendar fechaNacimiento;
```

Comment: It's an old answer but I still want to add this point : using `DataType.SERIALIZABLE` is ok to persist the data. But you won't be able to make a comparison on your field (like selecting a record with a given date, for example)